# Mysql Trigger - Compound statements

Tags: mysql, triggers

Looking for some help on mysql triggers and using multiple statements.

What I am trying to achieve is BEFORE an insert I want to copy records from active table ->history table and then delete them, THEN do the insert.  The code works perfectly for the copying of the records from active->history.  But the Trigger bonks as soon as I put the delete in ie. it will still move the records but will NOT delete the old rows.

Thoughts/ideas?

```
CREATE 
DEFINER = 'root'@'%'
TRIGGER tradesfinder.On_Checkin_active_Insert
BEFORE INSERT
ON tradesfinder.user_checkin_active
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

INSERT INTO user_checkin_history
SELECT *
FROM user_checkin_active
WHERE user_id = new.user_id;

DELETE FROM user_checkin_active 
WHERE user_id = new.user_id;
END
```

Thanks in advance.

C

Comment: Do you have a `delimiter` statement before the trigger?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an update if the id exists not delete and then insert. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO `user_checkin_active` (user_id, b, c) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b =new.b, c = new.c;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the trigger syntax as shown above will not work as expected. Instead of triggering a select *, it would be better to work with the new row. So instead of "insert into user_checkin_history select *..." you would instead want to have the trigger to have soemthing to the effect of "insert into user_checkin_history (a,b,c,d) values (new.a,new.b,new.c,new.d)" which then inserts ONLY the contents of the new row.

Otherwise, you end up picking up ALL rowsx for the given user EACH time the user inserts something. That may not be what you intended.